# PHP echo money format plus amount

Tags: php, html-table, money-format

I have a table for total report and I want to get a value from a database and format the numbers and have an output like this **PHP 10,000.00** not like this **10000**

Here is my trial PHP code. I have a table for print of Total reports and got problem in formatting the total amount.

```
function printpage()
{
window.print()
}

</script></head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
<center>
<div class="alert alert-success" align="center"><h1>TOTAL REPORT</h1></div>
<br />
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered" border="1"  width="900">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>

            <th>Start of Event</th>
            <th>End of Event</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Confirmation</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
      $db=mysql_select_db('pm')or die(mysql_error());

            $query=mysql_query("select * from reservation  ")or die(mysql_error());
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $id=$row['id'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <?php  $row['id'] ?>
            <td><?php echo $row['firstname'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['lastname'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['arrival']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['departure'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['result'] ?></td>

            <td><?php 
            $number = 'payable';
            $payable = 0;
            setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_PHP");
    echo $row("The price is %i", $payable);
   ?>  </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['confirmation'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT sum(payable) FROM reservation") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<?php }

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT result(qty) FROM rooinventory") or die(mysql_error());
while ($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
?>  
<div class="pull-right">
    <div class="span">
        <div class="alert alert-info"><i class="icon-credit-card icon-large">      </i>&nbsp;Total Amount:&nbsp;<?php echo $rows1['sum(p)']; ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locale is wrong and $number should actually be a $row value.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $row['payable']);
```

For Windows machines

```
echo '$' . number_format(floatval($row['payable']));
```

Comment: but the number is in my table row payable. i want to get the number there and have a format in my print

Comment: If you're having a problem getting a value from a database, then the answer is not about how to format that number.  you'll need to get the row from your table and access in something like $row['payable'].  It doesn't seem like your question is well formatted.  If your problem is actually retrieving a value from a database table, then the formatting is not going to help you get there.

Comment: absolutely, it is possible, but you haven't provided any code about how you're getting any information from your database.  You said "table" and you showed part of your code with a <td> and a bad setlocale function.  I suggest you ask a new question that talks about how to read data from a database.  Or Google it.

Comment: Im sorry, I've searched about the echo money_format and that's what I see in google and I'd just try it in my code but something's wrong with it. but thanks a lot!

Comment: then please provide more context to your example.

Comment: It says Fatal error: Call to undefined function money_format()

Comment: money_format does not work on windows systems. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

Comment: I use number_format() and it has the error "Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in"

Comment: number_format's first parameter needs to be a float value, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code need to be fixed. Also en_US might not be enough depending on your system (ie: Debian needs en_US.utf-8):

```php
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US.utf-8");
echo money_format("The price is %i", $row['payable']);
```

Comment: the number is in my table i just want to have a format for it and have money sign

Comment: If it is in your table, looking at your code, you could get it like in my edited example. But I'm affraid I don't know about a locale called "en_PHP", but that will probably never work. If on the other hand you don't have "payable" in your query "select * from reservation", you should probably ask about the query itself, as @alan-asher told you.

Comment: I have payable in my table. If it's not possible I want to echo PHP + payable. how it will be?

Comment: I use number_format() and it is the error "Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in"

Comment: "PHP" is not a currency, and not a locale that I'm aware of... If you want to concat "PHP" with a formated number, you should use number_format() instead. Then if $row['payable'] is a string, maybe casting it to float will help. Maybe you can show us the $row content?